# await in expression - valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, promise, webstorm

The following code seems to work for me in Node 9.x (don't ask, I know this is not supposed to be used by end users, but here we are). The problem is, IntelliJ WebStorm says it has unreachable code.

```
return await firstPromise() || await secondPromise();
```

I've written little test programs and tried this with all permutations of each part resolving true, false, or rejecting a promise. It seems to do the right thing. Is WebStorm just wrong here?

Comment: `await secondPromise()` is unreachable because `await firstPromise()` is already truthy, so `await secondPromise()` is never reached. Whenever `return` happens and some of the code is never executed, most editors give this type of error.

Comment: @PHPglue How would an editor know that `await firstPromise()` is always truthy?

Comment: @PHPglue `await firstPromise() is already truthy` Not necessarily. https://jsfiddle.net/eo8g2p5a/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in PhpStorm.

Comment: I can reproduce it if I put the code in a function that isn't declared `async`. But it also shows a syntax error after `await`.

Comment: After reviewing `@CertainPerformance`s comment. It might be an editor issue.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use Node 9.x for end users  what makes you think otherwise? Because it's not an LTS version?

Comment: I tried to "answer" this question with Barmar's point, but the reviewers at Stack Overflow said I needed to seek clarification from myself.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.